# Regular Expression Match to test for a valid year

Tags: regex, string, validation, string-matching

Given a value I want to validate it to check if it is a valid year. My criteria is simple where the value should be an integer with `4` characters. I know this is not the best solution as it will not allow years before `1000` and will allow years such as `5000`. This criteria is adequate for my current scenario.

What I came up with is

`\d{4}$`

While this works it also allows negative values.

How do I ensure that only positive integers are allowed?

Comment: fwiw I created a node.js project, [to-regex-range](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/to-regex-range) to automatically create these ranges. It's harder than it might seem if you need to generate the regex to test for a range of years.

Comment: Why limit your validation to 4 digit years? http://longnow.org/

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You need to add a start anchor `^` as:

```
^\d{4}$
```

Your regex `\d{4}$` will match strings **that end with 4 digits**. So input like `-1234` will be accepted.

By adding the start anchor you match only those strings that **begin and end** with 4 digits, which effectively means they must contain only 4 digits.

Comment: Damn! Mine was so flawed that it would have even accepted `whateverblahblah2323`. Now I understand why a little learning is dangerous :O

Comment: This will break in the year 10,000.

Comment: @sferik: Doesn't matter. The original poster specifically stated he wanted to check for four characters. He did not state he wanted the year 10,000 to be valid input, so accepting `10000` would be a bug.

Comment: @sferik: The program will be gone for centuries by then. If not, it is best to worry about 9,000 years in the future. Following the principle of YAGNI, the approach is valid.

Comment: @Phil not just the program, will be highly doubtful that the human race or the planet will be around at that time.  And for sure robots will be doing most of the coding long before that and laughing to each other as they try to rewrite our terrible code.

Answer (score 229):

Years from 1000 to 2999

```
^[12][0-9]{3}$
```

For 1900-2099

```
^(19|20)\d{2}$
```

Comment: I's better to use non-capturing group: `^(?:19|20)\d{2}$`

Comment: How would I validate a 4 digit year between 2011 & 2099?

Comment: How can I add `(19|20)\d{2}` to my regex in order to validatate a birthdate format ? This is my regex `/^[0-9]{1,2}\/(0[1-9])|(1[0-2])\/[0-9]{4}$/` I want to ensure that the year has always 4 digits and begins wither 19** or 20**

Comment: Use  ^(19|2[0-9])\d{2}$  for years 1900 - 2999

Answer (score 22):

The "accepted" answer to this question is both incorrect and myopic.

It is incorrect in that it will match strings like `0001`, which is not a valid year.

It is myopic in that it will **not** match any values above 9999. Have we already forgotten the lessons of [Y2K](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)? Instead, use the regular expression:

```
^[1-9]\d{3,}$
```

If you need to match years in the past, in addition to years in the future, you could use this regular expression to match any positive integer:

```
^[1-9]\d*$
```

Even if you don't expect dates from the past, you may want to use this regular expression anyway, just in case someone invents a time machine and wants to take your software back with them.

Note: This regular expression will match all years, including those before the year 1, since they are typically represented with a BC designation instead of a negative integer. Of course, this convention could change over the next few millennia, so your best option is to match any integer—positive or negative—with the following regular expression:

```
^-?[1-9]\d*$
```

Comment: No, it likely won't. But someone (archeologist? historian?) might need to match years for 8000 years ago. :D And Doc Brown might need it...

Comment: i used this to limit range from 1000-9999 ^[1-9]\\d{3}$ thats because the application we have to provide data to, accept 4 digits numbers only :(

Comment: Awesome answer. I'd make it the following to accept the year 0 as well: ^(-?[1-9]\d*|0)$

Comment: I would say 0001 is a valid year.  And there is no way in hell this code is gonna be running in the year 2080 let alone 9999.  y2k was 1960 looking forward 40 years, not looking forward 7000+   But yeah ... apart from that, some useful tidbits

Comment: This will also match `1234567` so better omit the `,` -> `^[1-9]\d{3}$`

Answer (score 13):

This works for 1900 to 2099:

```
/(?:(?:19|20)[0-9]{2})/
```

Comment: looks to me like it would only go to 2099. BTW the OP is asking how to only allow positive 4 digit number.

Comment: bah, 2099 is what I meant. thanks. and now I see the positive integers part.

Comment: I created a project, [to-regex-range](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/to-regex-range) to automatically create these ranges

Answer (score 6):

Building on @r92 answer, for years 1970-2019:

```
(19[789]\d|20[01]\d)
```

Comment: Your answer allows `197999`

Comment: I don't think it does... The first part of the regex matches number starting with 19, then any of 7,8 or 9, followed by a SINGLE number. The regex `19[789]\d\d\d` would allow `197999 `

Comment: `/(19[789]\d|20[01]\d)/.test(1970324) >> true`

Comment: yes, it will match the first 4 numbers (`1970`), not the last 3. What about `(19[789]\d|20[01]\d)[^0-9]`? That would match `1970 324` but not `1970324`

Comment: I found this one useful for finding the movie year from a filename... in this case we want stuff from 1930s onwards... but we then exclude the 1024 that is added to the end for video quality

Answer (score 4):

To test a year in a string which contains other words along with the year you can use the following regex: **\b\d{4}\b**

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, the accepted answer doesn't seem to be valid PCRE.

Comment: This should be the answer to the question

Answer (score 3):

In theory the 4 digit option is right. But in practice it might be better to have 1900-2099 range.

Additionally it need to be non-capturing group. Many comments and answers propose capturing grouping which is not proper IMHO. Because for matching it might work, but for extracting matches using regex it will extract 4 digit numbers and two digit (19 and 20) numbers also because of paranthesis.

This will work for exact matching using non-capturing groups:

`(?:19|20)\d{2}`

Answer (score 2):

Use;

```
^(19|[2-9][0-9])\d{2}$
```

for years 1900 - 9999.

No need to worry for 9999 and onwards - A.I. will be doing all programming by then !!!  Hehehehe

You can test your regex at https://regex101.com/

Also more info about non-capturing groups ( mentioned in one the comments above )  here http://www.manifold.net/doc/radian/why_do_non-capture_groups_exist_.htm

Answer (score 1):

you can go with sth like [`^-]\d{4}$`: you prevent the minus sign `-` to be before your 4 digits.
you can also use `^\d{4}$` with `^` to catch the beginning of the string. It depends on your scenario actually...

Answer (score 1):

**/^\d{4}$/**
This will check if a string consists of only 4 numbers. In this scenario, to input a year 989, you can give 0989 instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your integer into a string. As the minus sign will not match the digits, you will have no negative years.

Answer (score 0):

I use this regex in Java `^(0[1-9]|1[012])[/](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](19|[2-9][0-9])[0-9]{2}$`

Works from 1900 to 9999

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match YYYY or YYYYMMDD you can use:

```
^((?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d)(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:[2468][048]|[13579][26])00))(?:0?2(?:29)))|(?:(?:[1-9]\d{3})(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(?:31))|(?:(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])(?:29|30))|(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])))))|(?:19|20)\d{2})$
```

Comment: How can convert YYYYMMDD or DDMMYYYY into YYYY.MM.DD or DD.MM.YYYY. I have string like 20200315 and I want to convert to 2020.03.15 in Dart. Also incoming string might be 17042021 then I need to convert to 17.04.2020 in Dart. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this one.

```
([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/([0-1][0-2])\/(19[789]\d|20[01]\d)
```

Comment: They want to match year only. Moreover your regex matches `00/00/2000` or `31/02/1999` and many more false dates.

Comment: Is might help you ([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/([0-1][0-2])\/(19[789]\d|20[01]\d)

Comment: ```(0[1-9]|1[0-2])``` is a much better expression for the month

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to match a string which ends with a year (4 digits) like this for example:

```
Oct 2020
Nov 2020
Dec 2020
Jan 2021
```

It'll return `true` with this one:

```
var sheetName = 'Jan 2021';
var yearRegex = new RegExp("\b\d{4}$");
var isMonthSheet = yearRegex.test(sheetName);
Logger.log('isMonthSheet = ' + isMonthSheet);
```

The code above is used in [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).

Here's the link to test the Regex above: https://regex101.com/r/SzYQLN/1

Comment: This, not only is going to match `Oct 2020` but also `Oct 20202`,  `Oct20202`

Comment: @RanhiruJudeCooray improved the regex.

Answer (score 0):

> You can try the following to capture valid year from a string:

```
.*(19\d{2}|20\d{2}).*
```

Comment: This allows arbitrary text before and after the year, which is not what the question is looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Works from 1950 to 2099 and value is an integer with 4 characters

```
^(?=.*?(19[56789]|20\d{2}).*)\d{4}$
```