# python check if year is in string

Tags: python, regex

Say i have a list of sentences, many of which contain numbers (but not all):

```
mylist = [
"The current year is 2015 AD.",
"I have 2 dogs."
...
]
```

I want to know which elements in the list contain a valid year (say, between 1000 and 3000). I know this is a regex issue, and i have found a few posts (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number)) that address detecting digits in strings, but nothing on full years. Any regex wizards out there?

Comment: Or [Regular expression match to test for a valid year](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4374185), but that doesn't contain the right answer: don't use regex. Then there's also [Regular expression numeric range](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1377926), which does.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a regex that will find 4 digit numbers where the first digit is between 1 & 3 and the next 3 digits are between 0 and 9 so I think you are looking for something like this

```
[1-3][0-9]{3}
```

If you want to accept strings that contain this you could do

```
.*([1-3][0-9]{3})
```

Comment: that's the regex i was looking for!

Comment: Note that this also allows the values 3001 to 3999

Comment: Did you notice that the other two answers, posted five minutes before this one, contain the same pattern, @nolanconaway?

Comment: @JoshCaswell i noticed! All of these answers gave me the regex i was looking for so i just picked the one i copied it out of.

Comment: I think  re.findall(r'.*([1-3][0-9]{3})', 'September 1, 2017 - June 30, 2018') should return two different years. Am I right?

Comment: Easy enough to remove the 3001-3999 case: `[12][0-9]{3}|3000`

But note that you don't need to use `.*` since `re.search( r'[12][0-9]{3}|3000', your_string )` will return a match anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a simple solution:

```
import re
mylist = [] # init the list
for l in mylist:
    match = re.match(r'.*([1-3][0-9]{3})', l)
    if match is not None:
        # Then it found a match!
        print match.group(1)
```

This will check to see if there is a 4 digit number between 1000 and 3999

Comment: This will also allow all values from 3001 to 3999

Comment: @aweis, yes I know. That is why I said it will allow for numbers between 1000 and 3999. I think [1000,3000] was really just an example

Answer (score 3):

Well a year can so fare be a lot of things. most commen it is 4 digits long yes, but it is just a number. If you want all years from 1000 and till 9999 you can use this regex: `([1-9][0-9]{3})` but to match the range you need: `([1-2][0-9]{3}|3000)`