# check if the directory name is year python

Tags: python, django, regex

how can I check if the directory name is a year using python ?
If I have directories called 2018, 2019, 2020, test1, test2,
I want to get only directories which name is a year . 
in this case I want directories with name : 2018, 2019, 2020

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python check if year is in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930527/python-check-if-year-is-in-string)

Comment: Have you tried regular expressions? Let's consider you only want years from 0 to 9999, then this ```result = re.match(r'\d{4}$', my_string)``` matches exactly that. You can extrapolate from this to match your exact need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might get along with a regular expression:

```
^[12]\d{3}$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/jhsybg/1).

---

Or with the help of some programming logic:

```
import re

folders = ["2018", "2019", "2020", "test1", "200000000", "test2   djdsdjk"]

rx = re.compile(r'^\d+$')

filtered = [folder
            for folder in (int(item) for item in folders if rx.match(item))
            if 1900 <= folder <= 2100]
print(filtered)
```

This yields

```
[2018, 2019, 2020]
```