# Validate a 4-digit year using a range with regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, validation, date

I want to do something similar to what was required in this post:
[Regex Valid Year check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374185/regular-expression-match-to-test-for-a-valid-year/4374209#4374209)

I would like to do something similar but only with years between 2011 & 2099?

Thanks,
Mac

Comment: And why would you need a regex for that?

Comment: quickest method..

Comment: One of those guys had this for 1900-2099

^(19|20)\d{2}$

Comment: The quickest method is `if (year >= 2011  && year <= 2099) { ... }`.

Comment: Quickest in terms of coding? Testing? Maintenance? Running?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My taste would be for parsing as an integer (`Integer.parseInt()`) and checking the bounds with `<=` or similar. But if you insist on the regular expression:

```
^20(1[1-9]|[2-9][0-9])$
```

The first case covers 2011–2019, the other 2020–2099. I have not tested.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
^20((1[1-9])|([2-9][0-9]))$
```

it matches exactly from 2011 to 2099

Comment: if you remove the redundant parentheses it is same answer as Ole V.V.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^20[1-9][0-9]$
```

`^20` starts with *20*
`[1-9]` followed by *1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9*
`[0-9]` followed by *0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9*

Edit:
It will also accept 2010.

See this [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44264864/8086920)

Comment: Yes, it will. I tested your answer and it works perfect

Comment: Thanks for doing that. And for the happy outcome.